# How to get continuous Location (Lat and Lng) along with location address in same project?

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, android-fusedlocation

I want to show a continuous update of Lat and long along with location address .

I was able to receive continuous lat/lng but wasn't able to find the location address .

Basically , want to combine these two :
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: *How can I achieve this?* as usual: CTRL+C, CTRL+V

Comment: Off the top of my head, use the lat/long that you continuously receive and follow the instructions in link #2 to get the address.

Comment: @Selvin: i did , still not ...can u please try this as usual and let me know. it would be great help .

Comment: @MatterCat: i did it . but following link#2 didnt work and made me confuse

Comment: @Shipra_delhi you posted 2 good examples ... and you are unable to combine 'em ... what's you expect? a miracle? if you cannot do this by yourself how we can help you? giving a working code? it is not the way how SO works...

Comment: @Selvin: i expect you to combine 'em and show me a miracle . SIMPLE .

Comment: as Matter Cat wrote ... you have to get results from 1st example and pass em to the 2nd example ... this should be simple enough ...

Comment: @Selvin : yaar see , i am novice in this and got this project and seeing this example i am really got confuse that's why needed help . That's All .

Comment: @Selvin ohkay . Will try to pass and see . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can get a location address using Geocoder class

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> addresses;
String city;

try {

    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat,lon, 1);

    if (addresses.size() > 0) 
        city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```